# :tstart and :tend not seeming to work in org-clock-table, however, :block does seem to work

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I can generate a clock table for the whole month with:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 5 :block 2021-07  :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

This properly generates a clock table showing all items in my agenda logged in July.

Now, I want to restrict to only a specific range of days in July. I'm working off of [the clocktable docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) to achieve this.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 5 :block 2021-07 :tstart "<2021-07-22 Thu>" :tend "<2021-7-25 Sun>" :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

This doesn't work, it generates an identical table to the first one.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 5 :block nil :tstart "<2021-07-20>" :tend "<2021-7-25>" :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

This doesn't work, it generates a blank table (there are definitely times recorded in this range, by the way, I confirmed by generating tables in their buffers, and comparing the results to the working first example, so I know `agenda` is properly catching those files).

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 5 :tstart "<2021-07-20>" :tend "<2021-7-25>" :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

This doesn't work, it generates an empty table as well.

I thought perhaps the `block` is a parent filter, and that `:tstart` and `:tend` filter within that filter, so I tried.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :maxlevel 5 :block 2021 :tstart "<2021-07-20>" :tend "<2021-7-25>" :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

This generates a table for the whole year, with the caption

```
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2021-07-25 Sun 13:15], for the year 2021.
```

No errors, the only message I get is `Updating dynamic block ‘clocktable’ at line 8...done`.

**What's the correct way to use `:tstart` and `:tend` to generate an org-clock-table that covers a specific range of days?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope org-agenda-files :tstart "<2021-07-01 Thu>" :tend "<2021-07-25 Sun>" :maxlevel 8 :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :link t
```

Looks like you should write "<2021-**07**-25"> instead of "<2021-**7**-25">. (P.S. no `:block` needed).

Cf. `C-h f org-parse-time-string` and `C-h v org-ts-regexp0`.